# Edge list from txt to csv

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have a graph represented by a edge list on a txt file: 
0 1 
0 2 
0 3 
1 4

(Of course the graph is much more bigger)

I want to import the graph on a csv file, each column on a different excel column:
A B 
0 1 
0 2 
0 3 
1 4

Someone can tell me a way to achive this?

Answer (score 1):

You can open the txt file with Excel. Use File > Open or use Data ribbon > from Text. This will run the file through the data import wizard, which will prompt for delimiters, formats, data types etc. This way you'll have greater control over how the data will be displayed in Excel.

If you copy and paste from a text editor to a worksheet, Excel will use the most recent settings from the import wizard, which is not necessarily what you want to use this time.